# ERlang HEAP overflow

Tags: erlang, heap-memory, overflow

I have quite a program..

Its almost complete..

However I am seeing a heap crash after about 12 hours of running.

I remember hearing that you can't program erlang in a certain way if not when you recurse the stack builds up.  Can anyone provide an example of that??

And also is there any way to have a realtime monitor of what process' are stacking up?

Regards

EDIT - What about

```
loop() -> 
  receive
     {sys, Msg} ->
         handle_sys_msg(Msg),
         loop();
     {From, Msg} ->
          Reply = handle_msg(Msg),
          From ! Reply,
          loop();

     _ -> continue
  end,
  loop().
```

Comment: Your edit is tail recursive which would mean that it does not build anything on the stack.

Comment: As @TERRIBLE ADVICE very correctly points out your edit is NOT tail recursive

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even your edit is *not* tail-recursive:

```
loop() -> 
  receive
     {sys, Msg} ->
         handle_sys_msg(Msg),
         loop();
     {From, Msg} ->
          Reply = handle_msg(Msg),
          From ! Reply,
          loop();
      _ -> continue 
  end,
  loop().
```

The order of execution for one function is: `receive ... end, loop()`. Now, if you get a `{sys, _}` message, `loop/0` will be called from within the receive, transforming the order of execution above into something equivalent to:

```
 loop() ->
      receive
          loop() ->
               receive
                  ...
               end,
               loop(),
      end,
      loop() ->
         ...
```

The problem is that if you call `loop()` from within the receive, the VM still has to store the return point in order to run the `loop()` in place after the `receive`.

To make your function tail-recursive, you would need to do either:

```
loop() -> 
  receive
     {sys, Msg} ->
         handle_sys_msg(Msg);
     {From, Msg} ->
          Reply = handle_msg(Msg),
          From ! Reply;
      _ -> continue 
  end,
  loop().
```

or

```
loop() -> 
  receive
     {sys, Msg} ->
         handle_sys_msg(Msg),
         loop();
     {From, Msg} ->
          Reply = handle_msg(Msg),
          From ! Reply,
          loop();
      _ -> loop()
  end.
```

Where calling `loop()` really is *always* the last thing to be done in the function.

Comment: what about if the receive is in a "try" segment of a try-catch? Does the VM still store the return point in case there's an exception? (This wouldn't make sense because the exception would be caught in the nested "try"

Comment: yes. In case of a `try ... catch`, if the expression happens between both, the VM will store a stack frame and not be tail recursive. In that case use: `try risky_thing() of Res -> recursive_call() catch ... end` which will prevent this issue

Answer (score 2):

The process loop must be tail-recursive.

**DO NOT**

```
loop() -> 
  receive
     {sys, Msg} ->
         handle_sys_msg(Msg),
         loop();
     {From, Msg} ->
          Reply = handle_msg(Msg),
          From ! Reply,
          loop()
  end,
  io:format("Message is processed~n", []).
```

See: http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/processes.html

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could be used for monitoring the current heap usage of processes in you system. Just put it in a printout in a looping gen_server or just run it in the shell every once in a while.

```
lists:reverse(lists:keysort(2,
   [{Pid,catch element(2,process_info(Pid,total_heap_size))} || Pid <- processes()])).
```